# Trying to sort excel range by two columns using c#

Tags: c#, excel, sorting

I have a range in excel that I need to sort by two columns. The data will always range from Column A to Column AA and I need to first sort it by column A (which is a date column, so oldest to newest), then by column F (numeric column, smallest to highest). The number of rows will vary.

Here is what I've got so far, keep in mind I'm relatively new to c#.

```
         Excel.Worksheet JobDataSheet = new Excel.Worksheet();

         foreach (Excel.Worksheet tmpSheet in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets)
         {
             if (tmpSheet.Name == "Job Labour" || tmpSheet.Name == "Job Materials" || tmpSheet.Name == "Job Cost Report")
             {
                 tmpSheet.Delete();
             }
             if (tmpSheet.Name == "Job Cost")
                 JobDataSheet = tmpSheet;
         }


         int MyCount = JobDataSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;

          //Sort Collection by Date & Ref Line
         Excel.Range tempRange = JobDataSheet.get_Range("A2:A" + MyCount);
         Excel.Range tempRange2 = JobDataSheet.get_Range("F2:F" + MyCount);

         JobDataSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear();
         JobDataSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add(tempRange // First Key
                                           ,Excel.XlSortOn.xlSortOnValues
                                           ,Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending
                                           ,Type.Missing
                                           ,Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal);
         JobDataSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add(tempRange2 // Second Key
                                           , Excel.XlSortOn.xlSortOnValues
                                           , Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending
                                           , Type.Missing
                                           , Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal);

         JobDataSheet.Sort.SetRange(JobDataSheet.get_Range("A1:AA" + MyCount));
         JobDataSheet.Sort.Header = Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes;
         JobDataSheet.Sort.MatchCase = false;
         JobDataSheet.Sort.Orientation = Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortRows;
         JobDataSheet.Sort.SortMethod = Excel.XlSortMethod.xlPinYin;
         JobDataSheet.Sort.Apply();
```

At the `JobDataSheet.Sort.Apply();` line excel throws `"The sort reference is not valid. Make sure that it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort By box isn't in the same or blank."`

Comment: Is this not your actual code? Based on this it looks like you are sorting a blank Sheet?

Comment: I forgot to copy the section where I declare my sheet, I edited my post to include this section.I declare a tmpSheet variable and I use that in a loop to check for three specific sheets which I then delete if present. Next I check if the tmpSheet = "Job Cost" which is the sheet were the code needs to execute and I then make my JobDataSheet variable = my tmpSheet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what works for me:

```
private void SortExcel()
{
    //Set up
    Excel.Application oXL;
    Excel._Workbook oWB;
    Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
    Excel.Range oRng;
    Excel.Range oLastAACell;
    Excel.Range oFirstACell;

    //Start Excel and get Application object.
    oXL = new Excel.Application();
    oXL.Visible = true;

    //Get a new workbook.;
    oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Book.Xlsx"));

    //Get Sheet Object
    oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oWB.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

    //Get complete last Row in Sheet (Not last used just last)     
    int intRows = oSheet.Rows.Count;

    //Get the last cell in Column AA
    oLastAACell = (Excel.Range)oSheet.Cells[intRows, 27];

    //Move courser up to the last cell in AA that is not blank
    oLastAACell = oLastAACell.End[Excel.XlDirection.xlUp];

    //Get First Cell of Data (A2)
    oFirstACell = (Excel.Range)oSheet.Cells[2, 1];

    //Get Entire Range of Data
    oRng = (Excel.Range)oSheet.Range[oFirstACell, oLastAACell];

    //Sort the range based on First Columns And 6th (in this case A and F)
    oRng.Sort(oRng.Columns[1, Type.Missing],Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, // the first sort key Column 1 for Range
              oRng.Columns[6, Type.Missing],Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,// second sort key Column 6 of the range
              Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,  // third sort key nothing, but it wants one
              Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlGuess, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
              Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns, Excel.XlSortMethod.xlPinYin,   
              Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal,
              Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal, 
              Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal);
    }
```

Comment: @Cornelius Glad to here! Feel free to Accept this answer as the answer to you question by clicking the Checkmark next to the answer!

Comment: I added the following at the end `oWB.Save();oWB.Close();` to save the updated sheet with sort and close the Excel sheet but when I go back to open it, I get the following error: `Excel found unreadable content in 'file.xlsx'. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.` If I click yes, it does open and displays the Excel file with the sort. Any idea why and how to prevent it? Thanks. +1 btw for the code to work.

Comment: If I press Yes and open and save it as something else, the new file opens just fine. I wonder why the issue with the first file. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.